# Powerpoint exporting shapes same size

Tags: c#, html, powerpoint

I am trying to convert pptx to html using c# by exporting every picture as an image but although I've tried all different PpExportMode's, I could not export the shapes with the same size. For instance, an image that's height and width are both 0,37 cm in powerpoint (it's equal to 13.984251969), becomes 20*20 pixel when I exported it. Does anyone know how can I save these shapes with the same size ? I've tried these;

```
shape.Export(exportPath + "\\" + fileName, PpShapeFormat.ppShapeFormatPNG,(int)slide.Master.Width,(int)slide.Master.Height, PpExportMode.ppScaleToFit);   
shape.Export(exportPath + "\\" + fileName, PpShapeFormat.ppShapeFormatPNG,0,0, PpExportMode.ppScaleToFit);
```

with different PpExportMode's.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The two parameters after export type are the width and height of the image you want, in pixels.  It's not clear from your example what sort of numbers you're supplying or what size image (again in pixels) you want to end up with.

Comment: I couldn't understand what's unclear, I have and image on my pp slide that's width and height are both 0,37 cm. (I wrote in cm since pp shows it in cm). I want the same size image when I export (a png that is 0,37*0,37 cm which equals 13.98*13.98 in pixels), but I can not, the image I exported is 20*20 pixel.

Comment: First of all, you don't say what slide.Master.Width equals. Next, images don't have sizes in cm, inches etc. Some image formats allow you to SPECIFY that when imported, the image should display at a certain size, others don't. PNG, so far as I know, doesn't. Think pixels and ask PPT to export at ShapeSize_in_Inches * DesiredImageSize_In_Pixels * 10  (at last a starting point).

Comment: I was trying to export a shape with it's original size (for instance for shapes that are pictures, the size when I click Save As Picture in powerpoint), because if i could, while I composing the HTML, I can just use top and left distances while inserting the shape, I  don't have to use the height and width, but now, I also need these two parameters since the exported image's size is not same with the original size of the shape. But I couldn't do the same size although I've tried export method with different parameters.

Comment: Again, other than as measured in pixels, images have no size. They may pretend to, but they don't.  In any case, you may be better off providing height and width anyhow.  If you do, the browser can allocate space for the image and go on to compose the remainder of the page while it waits for the image to download.  If you leave height/width out, the page rendering has to wait for the image to download so the browser knows how much space it'll take up.  In other words, your pages will load more slowly.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.My goal is composing a HTML page that is same with my powerpoint slide(by exporting every shape as an image). I don't want to use width and height properties since there are several problems, for example for an horizontal line, the height property (shape.Height) returns 0 (because it's the height difference between right and left point of the line), and when I use height:0 px in HTML, it's unvisible. If I can could export this arrows shape with the same sizes in powerpoint, using only top and left distances I can place it in my HTML page.

Comment: You'd have to allow for special cases like lines.  .Line.Weight will give you the thickness of the line (in points).  For that matter, you'll need to take the .Line.Weight of other shapes into account as well.  Add a rectangle, check its .Height and .Width.  Now give it a 48 point outline and check again.  .Height and .Width don't change but obviously the shape is much taller/wider.  If you want its true size, you need to add the outline's weight to the height/width of the shape (at least with current versions where the outline is half inside/half outside the shape)